# incremental builds in Xcode server

Tags: xcode, git

I'm using Xcode server for CI and want to do git pull instead of always clone. Can you do that?

i tried the "clean" option in the bot settings; but, it still seem to clone the entire repo every time.

Comment: Why are you trying to change this behavior?

Comment: I have Xcode server configured to use a remote repository, a Stash server that is shared with the rest of my department. Not all of the department is using Xcode server, and I really want to be considerate of the other teams. We've found in the past that `git clone` is one of the most resource intensive operations for Stash, and that when multiple CI boxes do a fresh clone before every build, it tends to overload the Stash server. So I'd like my Xcode server to respect this and do a `git pull` instead.

Comment: There's nothing in the developer forums that I can find.

Comment: Maybe you should file a bug.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to avoid `git clone` when a new bot is created or just on every integration of an existing bot? The second one can be fixed by just setting Clean to Never. The first one I have no idea, since each Bot needs its own working copy of the repo.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with it for quite some time too.

This may help : http://matt.vlasach.com/xcode-bots-hosted-git-repositories-and-automated-testflight-builds/

Comment: I saw that article before, but I'm glad I took a second look. He says he ran into similar issues: "In my case, I use SSH to access my git repository.  However, I cannot for the life of me get Bots configured with SSH to properly pull from the repository. ...  Instead, I use HTTPS (with username and password) to access the source."

Comment: @RobertR, did you find something that might be helpful in terms of pull or clone? It is quite annoying that Xcode server can only do "clone" for each integration.